# Is there any datepicker/calendar component available in Seedstack 16.7 version?

Tags: date, datepicker, calendar, seedstack

We are using Seedstack 16.7, we want to use date picker for choosing date. Is there any ready to use component available?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. If your application is using Bootstrap 3, [UI bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is included automatically. It has a [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker) and a [timepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#timepicker).